# Can someone please translate this note to a friend? (Characters identified: 你是我的嘘声)

Tags: translation, character-identification

Someone wrote this to a friend of mine.  Can someone please translate it?

[image]

Comment: looks like 你是我的嘘声  although 4th and 5th characters appear too much split in two (like first one)
嘘声 xū shēng
hissing sound
to hiss (as a sign of displeasure)
xūshēng
1) hissing; hooting; catcall
2) hushing sound

Comment: Can you please rewrite your title, so that it doesn't seem so clickbait-y? I understand you want someone to translate this, but please don't do this in the future - it's only an eye-sore.

Comment: For future readers, please see [How do I self-answer “What does this say?”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say)

Answer (score 2):

It means :

> You are my hiss.

The characters on the strip of paper don't look like a native speaker's work. Normally even foreigners will attain some ease in pencilling out frequent characters like 我。 I therefore  assume a foreigner with very little practice wrote this and possibly confused some characters.